# Emacs - Open buffer list without replacing another buffer

Tags: emacs, buffer

I have one frame, one window.
I use Cx 3, I now have two windows.

I use Cx Cb in order to see the list of buffers, however it opens it in another window but doesn't put the focus on it. It is even more annoying if I had opened a buffer on the 2nd window.

I would prefer to either open the buffer list in the window which currently has the focus, or temporarily change the focus to the buffer list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I want to start by saying that the `ibuffer` function does similary to what you want and does so in the current window, its definitely worth checking out.

Now onto your actual question. `C-x C-b` by default calls the function `list-buffers`. If you search for that command using `C-h f` it will show you the documentation, from there you can view the source code for the function by clicking on the underlined text that says `buff-menu.el`.

Now we can view the source of the `list-buffers`, the first function called is `display-buffer`. That sounds promising. We can now use `C-h f` once again to search for the `display-buffer` command. Reading though this documentation we see that the variable `display-buffer-alist` dictates how the `display-buffer` and in turn how `list-buffers` works. We can then see that by adding `("*Buffer List*" . display-buffer-same-window)` to `display-buffer-alist` you will get the desired result.

All in all you simply need to put `(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist '("*Buffer List*" . display-buffer-same-window))` in your init file for your changes to take place.

Comment: Thank yoi very much for this complete answer. I'm questionning the defaut behavior, why does it work like this ? What's the purpose of changing some window's buffer ?

Comment: I don't know and I really don't like how they do this, thankfully it's easy to change. If you want to change the default action you can `(setq display-buffer-base-action display-buffer-same-window)`. Also if this answer fixes your problem feel free to mark it as accepted!

Comment: I will as soon as I test it. I like that it is easy to change, however I'd rather not change a lot of things so that I can use emacs on an other computer easily. Otherwise I would have change a lot of shortcuts

Comment: I tend to use git to keep my init.el file synced and then use `use-package` to install missing packages

Comment: I finally binded C-x C-b to ibuffer. How can I find the name of the function a shortcut calls ? And when I do C-h f I have the exact same problem it replaces a buffer of another window

Comment: To find the name of the function that a keybinding calls you can run `C-h k` and then type the keybinding.

Comment: For the help window issue you can check the variable `help-window-select`using `C-h v`. I have this in my init file: `(setq help-window-select t)`

Comment: I think this might have changed in emacs 27 as this solution does not work. I shall update when I get it working.

Comment: `wrong-type-argument listp display-buffer-in-previous-window` Doesn't work on `GNU Emacs 25.3.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9)
 of 2019-12-24`

Answer (score 1):

Please just try one of these:

1. open the buffer list who currently has the focus:

```
(defun my:list-buffers (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (display-buffer (list-buffers-no-select arg) '(display-buffer-same-window)))
```

2. change the focus

```
(defun my:list-buffers2 (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (select-window (list-buffers arg)))
```

Comment: utilising display-buffers-alist is the way to go.