# switch to buffer with C-x C-b without changing window

Tags: emacs, window, buffer

I usually have 2-3 windows open in emacs, and am particular about which buffer is shown where. While C-x C-f shows the buffer (file visited) in the current window, C-x C-b (and recentf-open-files from the recentf package) sometimes end up displaying it in another window, which then makes complicated rearrangements necessary.

Is there a way to force these commands to end up displaying the buffer in the window that was active when the C-x C-f or C-x C-b where issued?

Comment: A similar question was asked 12 hours again right [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403606/emacs-open-buffer-list-without-replacing-another-buffer)

Comment: Thanks, this reference solved my issue with a very simple remedy. I now have `(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist '("*Buffer List*" . display-buffer-same-window))` in my .emacs file. I'd accept this answer if it weren't a comment.

Comment: Its all good, I already got some points the first time, just glad I could help out ;)

Comment: After some use, I realized it does not work with C-x C-b. I get "wrong type argument: listp, display-buffer-same-window". It does, however, work with C-x C-f and recentf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function at issue `list-buffers` is a one-liner -- so just change `display-buffer` to `switch-to-buffer` and redefine the keyboard shortcut to point to the new function:

```lisp
(defun my-list-buffers (&optional arg)
"Display a list of existing buffers.
The list is displayed in a buffer named \"*Buffer List*\".
See `buffer-menu' for a description of the Buffer Menu.
By default, all buffers are listed except those whose names start
with a space (which are for internal use).  With prefix argument
ARG, show only buffers that are visiting files."
  (interactive "P")
  (switch-to-buffer (list-buffers-noselect arg)))

(define-key ctl-x-map "\C-b" 'my-list-buffers)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Works fine! Why they didn't do it in core team? It was annoying for me, too, that `C-x C-b` opened buffer list somwhere else than my cursor was and opened the new buffer in that other window ... Now it works how it should work ... And I couldn't see any rules (it was not that window before the current cursor ... seemed really random choice ... did somebody noticed which window that was jumping to so arbitrarily? - maybe the last one to which I `C-x o`-ed?).

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim -- Here is a link to the documentation explaining how `display-buffer` works.  The `display-buffer-alist` and other aspects of the `display-buffer` family of functions is rather complex and many experienced Emacs users seem to avoid answering questions on emacs.stackexchange.com and/or stackoverflow.com due to fear of opening a Pandora's Box ...  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Window-Choice.html#Window-Choice  Answers are still posted to these questions, but those answers are generally from junior Emacs users ...

Comment: hahaha thank you a lot! So complex rules ... that's why I couldn't make sense. xD - anyway thank you a lot for your neat answer! - crazy how complex emacs' behaviour can be ... who had so much time to creat this function? ;)

Comment: Honestly this should be the default behavior or the existing behavior should be modified such that the active window is in the buffer-list window. Thank you so much for the answer! Now, I wonder why do core team not switch focus to new windows when you create them?? even C-x 2 stays in the current window...